# Find a map $\Phi$ for a definite Jacobian matrix.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $f_i(x):\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a $C^{\infty}$ function, and

$$
A(x)=
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
f_2(x)&1\\
\vdots&&\ddots\\
f_n(x)&&&1 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Does there exist a differential map $\Phi:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}
^n$ whose Jacobian matrix is $A(x)$?

I think $f_i(x)$ is equal to $x_i+C_i(x_1)$ for a differential function $C_i\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$, but I cant prove it.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I think $f_i(x)$ is equal to $x_i+C_i(x_1)$ for a differential function $C_i\in C^{\infty}(R)$, but I cant prove it.

Comment: Just thought I'd let you know that the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ should be typed up as \mathbb{R} between dollar signs. Writing just $R$ can cause confusion.